# Am I allowed to add a direct download link into my answer?

Tags: discussion

Even if the case is a third-party freeware (or with any "free to distribute" license applied to it), will I be allowed to insert a mediafire/mega/4shared link to an answer?

For example I want to upload a program called RAF Manager (League of Legends related), which was really hard to find the one version that works (since the author of that program removed the download link, also from his FTP, for non-mentioned reasons). Also the program doesn't violate any game/company terms.

Comment: Does this link answer any question?

Comment: Well, if a third-party program is needed to let the person achieve what he/she wants, and is found nowhere (and you have it), then I think so.

Comment: In terms of third party tools with their own website, link to the downloads page, not the download, as a direct link will go out of date

Comment: As stated in my example, the author of that program removed the download link, also from his FTP, for non-mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no rules against linking to stuff you've uploaded on file sharing sites, you just need to adhere to the regular rules (e.g. no files that enable cheating in multiplayer).

However, in my experience these sorts of uploads often tend to rot, so I recommend also adding as much information as possible to your answer regarding other ways to obtain the file(s) - take [my answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/20228/122) as an example.